# Is RH 7.2 compatible with C++14?

Tags: rhel, gcc, c++

Is RH 7.2 compatible with C++14 ? any official doc please ?
otherwise, with which version of RH, C++14 is compatible please ?
thanks
BA

Comment: Are you asking about Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2, which is around 3 years out of date, or Red Hat Linux 7.2, which is around 19 years out of date?

Answer (score 1):

By default RHEL 7 [contains gcc 4.8](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19458) which doesn't support C++14, you need to use Developer Toolset 7 from Software collections. Official documentation is available [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/html/user_guide/chap-red_hat_developer_toolset) or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214415/how-to-install-c14-on-rhel-7-4) with shorter version on stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks a lot. FYI, I don't have any knowledge about this subject. really sorry,  do you mean that if I ask to install Developer Toolset 7, C++14 will be compatible with RH 7.2 ?

Comment: Distributions aren’t compatible with versions of the C++ standard, compilers are. By installing Developer Toolset 7, you get a version of GCC which supports C++14.

Comment: It seems that Developer Toolset 7 is not compatible with RH7.2;  am I right ?
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/html/user_guide/chap-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset#sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Compatibility (see Figure 1.1. Red Hat Developer Toolset 7.1 Compatibility Matrix

)